# In C++ is there a way for me to have a function without passing an argument?

Tags: c++

I have to write a code that outputs a formatted date when the user inputs 3 integers but also outputs a default date of 1/1/2019. I'm supposed to use a class and objects for this but i can't figure out how to get it to work without any arguments being passed from the object. Here's my current code

```
class Date
{
    private:
        int defaultDay = 1;
        int defaultMonth = 1;
        int defaultYear = 2019;
    public:
        Date()
        {
            int day = defaultDay;
            int month = defaultMonth;
            int Year = defaultYear;
        }
        void dateFormat(int day,int month,int year)
        {
            defaultDay = day;
            defaultMonth = month;
            defaultYear = year;
            cout << day << "/" << month << "/" << year << endl;
        }
}

int main()
{
    Date setDate,

    int day, month, year;

    cin >> day;
    while(day < 1 || day > 31)
    {
        cout << "Please enter a number between 1 and 31" << endl;
        cin >> day;
    }
    cin >> month;
    while(month < 1 || month > 12)
    {
        cout << "Please enter a number between 1 and 12" << endl;
        cin >> month;
    }
    cin >> year;

    setDate.dateFormat(day, month, year);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your constructor does nothing, other than assign temporary variables some values, but then never uses them. (not an answer to your question, just an FYI)

Comment: Have you considered the function `Date::readDate()`  and `Date::writeDate()`?  No arguments there.

Comment: `Date setDate,`   your error is the missing `;` on line 53;  also after your class definition ;)

Comment: Do you mean you should overload `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Date const&)` so it can be used like `std::cout << "the date is " << setDate << '\n'`?

Comment: _In C++ is there a way for me to have a function without passing an argument?_ I'm not sure, why `class` is needed for this. It can be achieved with a simple plain function with either default arguments, or an overload with no arguments. [**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/387235c023a3b387) The first option has the advantage that it can be called with day, or day and month as well. If this is considered as disadvantage instead, the second option should be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to make minimal changes to your code to show you some things you can do.

```
class Date
{
    private:
        int day = 1;
        int month = 1;
        int year = 2019;

    public:
        // Default constructor with no arguments.
        Date()
        {
        }

        // Constructor with arguments.
        Date(int _day, int _month, int _year)
        {
            day = _day;
            month = _month;
            year = _year;
        }

        //print me.
        void print() const {
            cout << day << "/" << month << "/" << year << endl;
        }
}

Date firstDate();  // Will use defaults
Date secondDate(1, 11, 2019); // November 11, 2019
```

Here's what I did... First, I renamed your fields. You don't need defaultDay etc unless you have another reason for them.

Next, I gave you two constructors, one with no arguments (called the default constructor), and one with arguments. Classes can have as many constructors as you want, as long as the signatures are different.

Then I made a print method.

I hope this helps.